# Extrat tar "Cannot open: File name too long"

Tags: command-line, tar

I made a tar with a directory on a remote machine with:

```
tar -czvf
```

I scp it to my local machine, where I wanted to untar it:

```
tar -xzvf
```

But I get : `Cannot open: File name too long`

On my local machine on lubuntu 12.04 I have:  `tar (GNU tar) 1.26`.

The remote machine is not accessible right now, I'll check the version after if needed.

I would like to extract without having to make a new tar, especially since the remote machine is offline.

And by the way if you know a way to make proper archive despite long name, I'll take it.

Comment: In the future, you may want to use `rsync` instead of `scp` and `tar`. `rsync` can transfer in compressed format by setting the right flags.

Comment: I 'll consider that, even if in this case the tar was made because I need large files in the remote machine. Thanks Bernhard.

Comment: Same problem might appear as `tar: [...] Cannot mkdir: File name too long`. Appeared on an encrypted filesystem when uncompressing a tar taken on a non-encrypted filesystem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tar` limit file names to 256 bytes (with GNU extensions). Linux File Systems support at least 256 bytes per file name. It means any file packed by `tar` may be extracted without error. So I suppose two causes:

1. The tarball is corrupted, check it by:

   ```
   $ tar -tvf tarball.tar
   ```

   You will see some erros if any.
2. You use a "virtual" file system like [fusecompress](http://code.google.com/p/fusecompress/) or [ecryptfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECryptfs) (with selective file copmpression/encryption) and your file name is a bit shorter or equal to the file system limit. The trick is when you mount a directory with fusecompress (for example) and create a file name `foo.bar` the virtual filesystem creates a file called `foo.bar.gz` and compress it transparently, but hides the real file name from you. And if you create a file with 254 byte name long you get an error because it will try to append a suffix to it.

   In this case simply extracting the tarball outside of the virtual file system should help:

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir /home/${USER}-temp
   $ sudo chown $USER /home/${USER}-temp
   $ tar -xvf tarball.tar -C /home/${USER}-temp
   ```

Anyway, try to trace it to get more information:

```
$ strace -o tar-strace.log tar -tf tarball.tar
$ ltrace -o tar-ltrace.log tar -tf tarball.tar
```

Comment: It is not a virtual file system. I have like thousands of files, there is one which is 158 caracters long without the path to it (with it it's 219). It starting and ending with a "#". I do not know this file, I guess if I removed it before "taring" it will work. The "tar -tvf" shows nothing special... and I do not know how to read the trace files (which are pretty long). Thanks a lot Dmitry.

Comment: Linux File Systems usually don't limit path length (see [comparsion table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits)). As for trace logs - if you're not aware with programming you could place files at [pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com) for example, but first ensure files contain no private data. Also if you don't need this particular file then you could just try to exclude it on extraction: `tar tar -xvf tarball.tar  --exclude="copyFileNameHere"` or even exclude all files  starting with the sharp sign: `tar -xvf tarball.tar  --exclude="#*"`

Comment: I can't paste them unfortunately (it is not my data). Thanks for your answer and this comment, I'll use it !

Answer (score 1):

Here is my workaround to save the files. When extracting tar, add these options:

- use --xform '*/sed/expression/*' to abbreviate the long names.
- use -T *file_with_names_list* to only extract problematic files rather than all archive.

Example:

put the long file names to /tmp/missing.txt first.

```
tar -x -T /tmp/missing.txt --xform 's/Beethoven-.*\.flac/B.flac/g' -f backup/home.tar
```

In my case all the problematic files were numbered audio tracks with metainformation, so clipping a bit of a name did not seem like an issue. You may need to think of a way to restore the original file name.